# Print line having two instances of same string in same line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to print lines which are having N(2 in this case) number of patterns in it.

For example: (input file)

```
cat data.txt
hello all
this is a text file
and this line is having one pattern
and this line is having two pattern, and here is another one : pattern. so its two in this line.
in this line pattern is three times , here is two more pattern and pattern
```

output: (print line containing two strings = pattern)

```
and this line is having two pattern, and here is another one : pattern. so its two in this line.
```

I was trying in following direction ,but `grep -c` is not helping me here.

```
string=pattern
while read line
     do

     count=$(echo $line |grep -c $string)
     #this always gives me 1, as its a count based on line. 
     if [ "$count" -eq 2 ];then
        echo $line
     fi

done <data.txt
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: `awk -F'your pattern' 'NF==3' data.txt` like this?

Comment: slick  and sweet! Thanks

Comment: I find your answer best!

Comment: I put it in comment because I am not sure if I understood your question right

Comment: Never use the word "pattern" as it's ambiguous. [edit] your question to replace all occurrences of "pattern" with either "string" or "regexp" and clarify if partial (the == there) or full (the != there) matches are required and include those cases in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk 'gsub(/pattern/,"&")==2' file
```

if you want to pass in the params

```
awk -vPattern="pattern" -vNum=2 'gsub(Pattern,"&")==Num' file
```

Comment: whats is the role of "&" ??

Comment: @RandomUser  Gsub reports the number of replacements it makes, but we don't actually want to replace anything so we can use `&` to replace the matched pattern with itself.

Comment: By not leaving a space between `-v` and `variable=value` you make the script unnecessarily gawk-specific. Also, don't use the word "pattern" as it's ambiguous - use "string" or "regexp" in each instance to show what it really is you're dealing with so the caveats become obvious. This is a good solution if partial matching of a regexp is what's wanted and double-escaping is OK, same as @cxw's solution and with the same caveats.

Answer (score 2):

In your existing code, replace the `count=` assignment with the following, using `gawk`:

```
count=$(echo $line |gawk -F "$string" -- '{print NF-1}')
```

`$string` can hold a word or a regular expression.  The `-F "$string"` assignment makes gawk split fields at instances of `$string`.  Therefore, the number of fields `NF` will be the number of occurrences of `$string`, plus 1 for whatever comes after the last occurrence of `$string` (even if that's an empty string).  `NF-1` is therefore the number of occurrences of `$string`.

**Example:** because of `-F pattern`, gawk will break the line

```
a pattern b pattern c
```

into three fields: `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Because there are three fields, there are two separators between those fields.  Therefore, `NF-1`, one fewer than the number of fields, is the number of separators between those fields.

Comment: @123 Sure, and who do you think just upvoted your answer? ;)  Anyway, you and I were answering at the same time, and this works fine with the OP's existing code.

Comment: They don't want the count though, they want to print lines with N matches, as displayed in their `Output:` section. Waittt... So this is a replacement for their count assignment? My bad :)

Comment: @cxw and 123 ,both of your solution worked. Thanks.  However I do not understand cxw solution . My be he wants to break it down ??

Comment: @RandomUser I added an example that I hope helps clarify.  Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
p1=pattern
n=2

pn="$p1"
for i in $(seq 2 $n); do
  pn="$pn.*$p1"
done
pn1="$pn.*$p1"

cat data.txt | egrep "$pn" | egrep -v "$pn1"
```